# Is there a way to have different columns on different tabs when rendering SSRS in Excel?

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have some columns that I only want to show up on a particular tab in Excel when rendering from SSRS. Is this possible? I'm using groups to split the data into different tabs, and the tabs get named with that group ID, but when I tell the show / hide "hide this column if it's not xyz group" it always hides it. In fact, I even said "if 1=0, hide this, otherwise show it" and it continued to hide it. Only way I can see the columns is if I tell it to Show--nothing conditional. Any ideas?

Comment: I do have a workaround, by the way. I can just duplicate my Tablix and filter, and have that be different. But I wondered if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: The column property is for the entire table and doesn't work on a row basis. Maybe just have the header and data be blank when not XYZ? Of course this would only work well when it's the last column.

Comment: Have you tried going the other way?  Making the data source of the SSRS report a data source for an Excel worksheet and code there appropriately?

Comment: Both interesting ideas. I'll play around with them.